# Open new message in Outlook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm pretty new at VBA and I am having problems with some code.

I need to create a Macro that opens a new Outlook window, copies the filtered cells and pastes them onto the body of the email. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to automate Outlook from Excel. To start an Outlook Automation session, you can use either early or late binding. Late binding uses either the Visual Basic `GetObject` function or the `CreateObject` function to initialize Outlook. For example, the following code sets an object variable to the Outlook Application object, which is the highest-level object in the Outlook object model. All Automation code must first define an Outlook Application object to be able to access any other Outlook objects.

```
Dim objOL as Object 
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

To use early binding, you first need to set a reference to the Outlook object library. Use the `Reference` command on the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) `Tools` menu to set a reference to `Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library`, where `xx.x` represents the version of Outlook that you are working with. You can then use the following syntax to start an Outlook session.

```
Dim objOL as Outlook.Application 
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
```

Most programming solutions interact with the data stored in Outlook. Outlook stores all of its information as items in folders. Folders are contained in one or more stores. After you set an object variable to the Outlook Application object, you'll commonly set a NameSpace object to refer to MAPI, as shown in the following example.

```
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application 
Set objNS = objOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
```

Once you have set an object variable to reference the folder that contains the items you wish to work with, you use appropriate code to accomplish your task, as shown in the following example.

```
Sub CreateNewDefaultOutlookTask() 
    Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application 
    Dim NewTask As Outlook.TaskItem 
    ' Set the Application object 
    Set objOLApp = New Outlook.Application 
    ' You can only use CreateItem for default items 
    Set NewTask = objOLApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem) 
    ' Display the new task form so the user can fill it out 
    NewTask.Display 
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.